# Select textboxes in specific DIV (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with some Javascript that I am writing. I have different DIV classes that have different names and I want to loop through each DIV class. So there is an outer loop to select the DIV class then there is an inner loop where it goes through that DIV class and selects all the textbox values.

My problem is with my JQuery selecting every textbox within every DIV. See below for code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Parent">

    <div class="Percentage">
    <pe:Percentage runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div class="Percentage">
    <pe:Percentage runat="server" />
    </div>

    <div class="Percentage">
    <pe:Percentage runat="server" />
    </div>

</div>
```

**USER Control**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="percentagerange.ascx.cs"   Inherits="js_percentagerange" %>
<div id="percentage">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPercentage1"  onchange="percentageCount()">50</asp:TextBox> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl1" >%   </asp:Label>
<br  /><br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPercentage2" onchange="percentageCount()">50</asp:TextBox> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1">%  </asp:Label>
<br /><br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPercentage3"   onchange="percentageCount()">0</asp:TextBox> <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2">%  </asp:Label>
<br /><br />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function percentageCount() {

    var totalPercentage = 0;

    $(".Parent").children().each(function(i, val) {
        alert($(".Parent").html());

        $(val + "[id*='txt']").each(function(i, val) {
            alert(this.value);
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Parent").children().each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).removeClass("Percentage").addClass("Percentage" + i);

    percentageCount();
});
```

Basically I want to loop through each .Percentage and access the textbox values. But for that DIV only. Not for every DIV

Comment: On document ready I select .parent and for each child class in .Parent I remove the class .Percentage and addClass .Percentage + i so each class has unique name. So in my PercentageCount function I want to loop through every .Percentage and view the values. Because of the Jquery I have used the inner loop selects every txt in every div instead of txts in current outer loop if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your issue correctly, but :

Instead of

```
alert(this.value);
```

try:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

Comment: That doesn't work. $(val + "[id*='txt']").each(function(i, val) { Selects every input with id = "txt" When I want to see values of textboxes in specific div only. Val contains div name.